# Getting value from Annotation

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I am trying to get the value/values specified inside an Annotation.

eg: If `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` is the annotation, i want to to get the value - *unchecked*.

```
public boolean visit(SingleMemberAnnotation annotation) {

    // returns the type name of the annotation - SuppressWarnings
    annotation.getTypeName();       

    return true;
}
```

Didn't see any methods inside the Annotation class to retrieve the same.
Any help/pointers are appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are visiting a `SingleMemberAnnotation` you should look into the `SingleMemberAnnotation` class rather than `Annotation`. [As you can see](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v6r0m1/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/SingleMemberAnnotation.html#getValue()) it has a `getValue` method which returns an `Expression`. This is the simplified case where you only have one expression like in `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`.

For ordinary annotations you will encounter a [`NormalAnnotation`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v6r0m1/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/NormalAnnotation.html) which will have a list of values which you can retrieve using the intuitively named method `values()`.

So, since these two types of annotation nodes are that different regarding how to retrieve the values, there is no such method in their common `Annotation` base class. For immutable nodes it would be possible to treat them more abstract representing the single member annotation’s value as a list of size one, however, since these AST nodes are mutable, i.e. the list returned by `NormalAnnotation.values()` supports adding, it can’t be provided on the base class.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it by class

```
    for (Annotation annotation : YourClass.class.getAnnotations()) {
        Class<Annotation> type = annotation.annotationType();
        System.out.println("Values of " + type .getName() + ":");

        for (Method method : type.getDeclaredMethods()) {
            System.out.println(" " + method.getName() + ": " +
                               method.invoke(annotation, null));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you have a class named Test with the SupressWarning, you should do:

```
Test.class.getAnnotation(SuppressWarnings.class).value;
```

Answer (score 0):

As far I know you can access the annotation with getAnnotation only which have runtime retention policy, but the SuppressWarnings is have retention policy as Source, I doubt that you could access it.